# Conditional probability the other ball is also orange

Tags: probability

An urn contains 4 colored balls: 2 orange and 2 blue. 2 balls are selected at random without replacement and you are told that at least one of them is orange. What is the probability that the other ball is also orange.

These are my thoughts:

Probability that one ball is orange (A) = $\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$

Probability that other ball is orange (B) = $\frac{1}{3}$

Now I get lost because how do you work out the intersection of A and B?

The answer is supposedly $\frac{1}{5}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possibilities:  both balls are orange, the first ball is orange and the second is blue, or the first ball is blue and the second is orange.

The probability that both balls are orange is
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$$
since two of the four balls are orange when the first ball is selected and one of the three remaining balls is orange if the first ball selected is orange.

The probability that the first ball is orange and the second is blue is
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$$
since two of the four balls are orange when the first ball is selected and two of the three remaining balls are blue if the first ball selected is orange.

The probability that the first ball is blue and the second is orange is 
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$$
two of the four balls are blue when the first ball is selected and two of the three remaining balls are orange if the first ball selected is blue.

The probability that the other ball is orange given that one of the balls selected is orange is the probability that both balls are orange given that at least one of them is, which is
$$\frac{\frac{1}{6}}{\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}} = \frac{1}{5}$$

Answer (score 2):

Imagine (it makes no difference) that the balls are drawn one at a time.

Let $A$ be the event both balls are orange, and let $B$ be the event at least one is orange. We want $\Pr(A|B)$, which by definition is $\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)$. Now we need to calculate two probabilities.

We have $\Pr(A\cap B)=(2/4)(1/3)$. Why? The event $A\cap B$ occurs precisely if both balls are orange. The first ball is orange with probability $2/4$, and given the first ball is orange, the probability the second ball is orange is $1/3$. Multiply.

To find $\Pr(B)$, calculate first the probability of the complement, the probability both are blue. This is $(2/4)(1/3)$, so the probability at least one is orange is $1-(2/4)(1/3)$.

Finally, divide and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

A = at least one is orange
C = none of them is orange
B = both are orange

You're looking for:
$P(B|A) = P(BA) / P(A) = P(B) / P(A) = P(B) / (1-P(C))$

Note that $BA = B$ because $B \subseteq A$. I used that above.

Now obviously:

$P(B) = P(C) = {2\choose2} / {4\choose2} = 1 / 6$

Substitute these in the last expression we got for $P(B|A)$ and you're done.

You get:

$\frac{1/6}{(1-1/6)} = \frac{1}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

You have a start, so here's a little more.

Let $X$ be the number of orange balls drawn. (Hypergeometric distribution. Find probabilities by the formula or, in this simple case, by tree diagram.)

Then show that $P(X = 2) = 1/6$, $P(X \ge 1) = 5/6$.

You seek $$P(X = 2|X \ge 1) = \frac{P(X = 2, X \ge 2)}{P(X \ge 1)}
= \frac{P(X = 2)}{P(X \ge 1)} = 0.2.$$

Explain each step carefully (especially the second equal sign), and you're done.

Addendum: This is a variant of a classical 'trick' probability problem:
"A family has two children. If I tell you at least one of them is a girl, what is the probability they are both girls." Many people quickly answer 1/2, which is, of course, wrong. The solution can be formulated as above, but now $X$ is binomial.